# Visual Studio 2010 Not Debugging .NET 2.0 Code

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

Please stick with me, this is a strange one.

Since upgrading from VS2008 to VS2010, some guys at work (and myself) found that we could no longer debug into our code. None of our breakpoints were being hit.

Without giving too much away, my work consists of writing .NET apps which run on top of a custom platform application we’ve developed. These apps are compiled to .NET 2.0. Debugging typically involves setting our platform app's exe as the startup program to debug into, and launching from there.

Interestingly, none of our developers working on Vista/Windows 7 machines had any issue – just the Windows 2003/XP crowd.

**Something about the combination of Visual Studio 2010, .NET 2.0, and Windows XP meant that we could no longer debug into our applications.**

I have absolutely no idea why this issue should arise only in Windows 2003 and XP machines. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Just to check, you're not compiling in to Release mode are you?

Comment: No, compiling to Debug mode. AFAIK all my VS2010 settings are the same as they were in VS2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to find a workaround, thanks to [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554067/cannot-debug-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-code-using-f5-in-mixed-mode-from-native-c-projects-or-c-project-with-start-external-program-set-to-native-exe). The issue seems to be that when debugging into code which is invoked from a native exe, Visual Studio will assume you’re debugging in .NET 4.0. Subsequently all your .NET 2.0 code will run, but the debugger won’t hit any of your breakpoints.

The fix is to give the debugger a helpful hint, in the form of a .exe.config file in the directory you’re launching your startup exe from. Something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This works as a fix, but doesn't actually answer why this happened in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It worked for me. It should be noted, though, that xxxx must be replaced with the version of the framework on your machine, which can be seen in the name of the corresponding directory, e.g.: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.

Comment: In the XML above question marks are missing. The first line should read like this: <?xml version ="1.0"?>

Comment: This worked nicely. We're doing the same thing, we debug through a Delphi 32-bit native application, that hosts our libraries. Visual Studio 2008 worked, 2010 didn't. With the above fix, a .exe.config file with that exact content, it worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the user option files for the projects and solution. Delete all obj and bin folders. More importantly, clear out the temporary files.

Using Visual Studio 2008 temporary files, for example:

- ("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
- ("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\ApplicationHistory")
- ("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
- ("%WINDIR%") & "\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files")

#### Real Life Example

I was debugging the Coding4Fun's *Searching the Desktop* VB.NET code at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/01/05/1417884.aspx. I noticed that on some source code files, the Navigation Bar was missing. Moreover, on the Editor's context menu the "Go To Definition" menu item was disabled. I closed Visual Studio, deleted the solution .suo file and all project .user files, re-opened the solution, and everything was back to normal.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, so apologies for that. I'll try it as soon as I can. But just out of interest, why would this affect my ability to debug into the code?

Comment: Clearing out the obj and bin folders removes any pdb files which hold debugging information. This would be the next step if deleting the suo does not solve the debugging behavior. This is the same as "cleaning the solution".

Comment: Removing Visual Studio's temporary files usually fixes reference problems. For instance, a breakpoint might not be hit because is using a different version of an assembly, which is stored in these temporary folders. This is more common with C# code in Web Site projects.

Comment: Your user debug configuration, such as breakpoints and other debug settings, are stored in the suo file. This file can get corrupted. If you have weird debugging behavior, deleting this file usually solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and explanation). Unfortunately this didn't seem to resolve my original issue. I'll bear it in mind in the future though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem and could not use the config file with Outlook.  Outlook complained when it tried to launch.  So, I did find another work-around.  I change the target platform to 4.0 instead of 2.0.  This brings back my debug mode.  I change it back before publishing and then do additional testing on another 2.0 machine without debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. After I converted a solution in Visual Studio 2010, the debug button did not work. In troubleshooting the problem I found that I could not delete one or two of the various files in the bin\debug folder.  It might have been the .vshost.exe file.  The lock on the file made me realize I had the solution open and minimized in Visual Studio 2008.  Whoops :)  I closed VS 2008, and it worked in VS 2010.